# How to generate random vectors without repetition?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

Say we have three elements, 0,1,2 and we want to generate 1000 random vectors of length 7 with these elements, i.e.

```
{2,1,0,0,0,0,2}
```

How can we do this without duplicates among these vectors?

Comment: Try a combination of `Tuples` and `RandomSample`.

Comment: `RandomSample[Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 7], 1000]`

Comment: @cvgmt You could post this as an answer since it fits the criteria and it runs very quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, there are $3^7=2187$ different 7-tuples, so there is indeed a considerable probability to encounter duplicates if we generate each 7-tuple independently. So, we use the following:

```
vectors=IntegerDigits[#, 3, 7] & /@ RandomSample[Range[3^7] - 1, 1000]
```

Comment: Can your answer be modified to work in case that the elements are not 3 successive numbers but a list to choose from? i.e. instead 0,1,2 to have {0,3,6}

Comment: {0,3,6} is not so much difference, just multiply `vectors` by `3`. More general `{a,b,c}` would require `vectors/.{0->a,1->b,2->c}.`

Comment: If the sample universe is really large, it would be better to use Span instead of Range to avoid memory issues, e.g., `RandomSample[Span[0, 3^7-1], 1000]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two similar methods of generating a pseudorandom list of unique vectors.  The first method uses `Union`.  It is a little faster than the second, which uses `DeleteDuplicates`.  The two methods are implemented as functions `f` and `g`

```
Clear[f]
f[nvect_, ndims_, list_] := Module[{a = {}, k},
  If[TrueQ[nvect <= Length[list]^ndims],
   While[(k = Length[a]) < nvect,
    a = Union[a, RandomChoice[list, {nvect - k, ndims}]]
    ]];
  RandomSample[a]]

Clear[g]
g[nvect_, ndims_, list_] := Module[{a = {}, k},
  If[TrueQ[nvect <= Length[list]^ndims],
   While[(k = Length[a]) < nvect,
    a = DeleteDuplicates@Join[a, RandomChoice[list, {nvect - k, ndims}]]
    ]]; a]
```

Since `Union` returns an ordered array, function `f` uses `RandomSample` to return a pseudorandom permutation of the ordered array.  Both functions return an empty set if you ask for an impossibly large number of unique vectors.

Timing tests on `f` and `g` give, for 1000 unique vectors,

```
tf = RepeatedTiming[f[1000, 7, {0, 1, 2}], 5];
tf // First

(*  0.002  *)

tg = RepeatedTiming[g[1000, 7, {0, 1, 2}], 5];
tg // First

(*  0.003  *)
```